# How to use readline autocompletion without input()

Tags: python-3.x, readline

I want to use [readlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) autocomplete functionality, but I don't want to use pythons input() function. However autocomplete doesn't work when I don't use input(). I want know how to make it work.

```
import readline
import sys

commands = ['start', 'pause', 'stop']

def completer(text, state):
    options = [i for i in commands if i.startswith(text)]
    if state < len(options):
        return options[state]
    else:
        return None

readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
readline.set_completer(completer)

while True:
    prompt = 'cmd: '
    # line = input(prompt)
    sys.stdout.write(prompt)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    print(line)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use stdin.readline instead of input?

Comment: I want to make make a program that uses the autocompletion from readline, but that doesn't get stuck waiting for input. I think that if i can get the autocomplete functionality using stdin.readline, that then I can make it work without getting stuck.

Comment: stdin.readline still blocks just like input  does. The readline completer attaches to the input function specifically. It also attaches to the python interpreter when you start interactive mode.

Comment: So if I want to use the completer, I need to use input(). And thus, I can never use autocompletion while waiting non-blocking for input. right?

Comment: "I can never use autocompletion while waiting non-blocking for input. right?" You first need to find something that lets you do non-blocking input.